# Grouping by a variable, then finding proportion of missing values for each column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with a factor variable and columns with a couple NA's as shown.

```
var col1 col2 col3
C    1    NA   1
A    NA   1    1 
C    NA   NA   NA
A    1    NA   1
B    NA   1    1
A    1    1    1
B    1    NA   1
B    1    1    1
C    NA   NA   1
B    NA   1   1
```

I'm looking for a way to group the variables and get the proportion of missing values for each column, grouped by the levels in 'var'. The output should look like this:

```
var col1 col2 col3
A    0.33 0.33  0
B    0.5  0.25  0 
C    0.66 1.00  0.33
```

Any method is fine and different methods would be appreciated, but a simple dplyr method would be preferred. Thanks!

**Edit:** I'm looking for a method that would allow me to do this for several columns at once and return a dataframe similar to the one I've shown above.

Say my data is named 'df' then, I'd like to do get the proportion of missing for all columns at once **without having to type out the names manually again.**

The following code doesn't work but it's a general idea of what I want to achieve. Maybe a function could help but I'm not sure how I'd approach it.

`df %>% group_by(var) %>% summarise(names(df[,-1]) = sum(is.na(names(df[,-1])))/n())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a more general `dplyr` solution with `summarise_each`, which will accept any number of columns:

```
df1 <-read.table(text="var col1 col2 col3
C    1    NA   1
A    NA   1    1
C    NA   NA   NA
A    1    NA   1
B    NA   1    1
A    1    1    1
B    1    NA   1
B    1    1    1
C    NA   NA   1
B    NA   1   1",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
group_by(var) %>%
summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.))/length(.)))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
    var      col1      col2      col3
  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     A 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
2     B 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.0000000
3     C 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in a data frame `data`, you could do the following:

```
## Your data:
data <- structure(list(var = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), 
    class = "factor"), col1 = c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA), 
    col2 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1), 
    col3 = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), 
    .Names = c("var", "col1", "col2", "col3"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)
outDf <- data %>% group_by(var) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(col1 = sum(is.na(col1))/n(),
                  col2 = sum(is.na(col2))/n(),
                  col3 = sum(is.na(col3))/n())

outDf 
### A tibble: 3 × 4
##     var      col1      col2      col3
##  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
##1      A 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
##2      B 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.0000000
##3      C 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.3333333
```

**Edit:**
To apply it to all columns with one call, you can use:

```
outDf <- data %>% group_by(var) %>%
  dplyr::summarise_all(function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(x))

outDf
### A tibble: 3 × 4
##     var      col1      col2      col3
##  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
##1      A 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
##2      B 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.0000000
##3      C 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.3333333
```

Comment: If I had multiple columns, is there a way I could apply a function to return all the columns in one go without having to type it out repeatedly

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
# Create some arbitrary matrix
rs <- 100
dat <- data.frame(matrix(1,rs,3))

for(i in 1:rs){
dat[i,sample(1:3,2,)] <- NA
}

dat <- cbind(rep(c("A","B","C"),rs)[1:rs],dat)

colnames(dat)[1] <- "var"

# Use the by function with an apply statement
by(dat[,c("X1","X2","X3")],dat[,"var"],function(x) apply(x,2,function(z){
    n <- length(z)
    miss <- sum(is.na(z))
    prop <- miss/n
    }))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~var, data, FUN = function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(x), na.action=NULL)
#  var      col1      col2      col3
#1   A 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
#2   B 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.0000000
#3   C 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.3333333
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x))/.N), var]
```